# How to get boolean result in annotate django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a filter which should return a queryset with 2 objects, and should have one different field. for example:

```
obj_1 = (name='John', age='23', is_fielder=True)
obj_2 = (name='John', age='23', is_fielder=False)
```

Both the objects are of same model, but different primary key. I tried usign the below filter:

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(name='John', age='23').annotate(is_fielder=F('plays__outdoor_game_role')=='Fielder')
```

I used annotate first time, but it gave me the below error:

```
TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): False.
```

I am new to Django, so what am I doing wrong, and what should be the annotate to get the required objects as shown above?

Answer (score 8):

The solution by @ktowen works well, quite straightforward.
Here is another solution I am using, hope it is helpful too.

```py
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    is_fielder=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(plays__outdoor_game_role='Fielder'),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    )
)
```

Here are some explanations for those who are not familiar with Django ORM:

**Annotate** make a new column/field on the fly, in this case, `is_fielder`. This means you do not have a field named `is_fielder` in your model while you can use it like `plays.outdor_game_role.is_fielder` after you add this 'annotation'. `Annotate` is extremely useful and flexible, can be combined with almost every other expression, should be a MUST-KNOWN method in Django ORM.

**ExpressionWrapper** basically gives you space to wrap a more complecated combination of conditions, use in a format like `ExpressionWrapper(expression, output_field)`. It is useful when you are combining different types of fields or want to specify an output type since Django cannot tell automatically.

**Q object** is a frequently used expression to specify a condition, I think the most powerful part is that it is possible to chain the conditions:

1. AND (&): `filter(Q(condition1) & Q(condition2))`
2. OR (|): `filter(Q(condition1) | Q(condition2))`
3. Negative(~): `filter(~Q(condition))`

It is possible to use Q with normal conditions like below:
`(Q(condition1)|id__in=[list])`

The point is Q object must come to the first or it will not work.

**Case When(then)** can be simply explained as `if con1 elif con2 elif con3 ...`. It is quite powerful and personally, I love to use this to customize an ordering object for a queryset.

For example, you need to return a queryset of watch history items, and those must be in an order of watching by the user. You can do it with for loop to keep the order but this will generate plenty of similar queries. A more elegant way with **Case When** would be:

```py
from django.db.models import Case, Exists

item_ids = [list]
ordering = Case(*[
    When(pk=pk, then=pos)
    for pos, pk in enumerate(item_ids)
])
watch_history = Item.objects.filter(id__in=item_ids).order_by(ordering)
```

As you can see, by using `Case When(then)` it is possible to bind those very concrete relations, which could be considered as 1) a pinpoint/precise condition expression and 2) especially useful in a sequential multiple conditions case.

Comment: There is a syntax error in one of your examples: `(Q(condition1)|id__in=[list])`. `a=b` cannot be used as an expression. What did you intend here?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Case/When` with `annotate`

```
from django.db.models import Case, BooleanField, Value, When
Model.objects.filter(name='John', age='23').annotate(
    is_fielder=Case(
        When(plays__outdoor_game_role='Fielder', then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField(),
    ),
)
```